# Simplifying a recursive function with 2 variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Given the following recursive function:
$$a_{n+1}=a_{n}+2b_{n}$$
$$b_{n+1}=a_{n}+b_{n}$$
With $a_1 = 3$ and $b_1 = 2$, I'm trying to figure out how to simplify the function in order to calculate $a_n$ for a large value of $n$ and haven't succeeded.

If there is a method to simplify $a_n$ or if you can induce a pattern of any sort please post it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you familiar with matrices? If yes, then let $\mathbf{v}_{n}=\begin{bmatrix}a_n\\b_n\end{bmatrix}$. Now we can write this as $$\mathbf{v}_{n+1}=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\mathbf{v}_n.$$ Now try to diagonalize this matrix.

Comment: If you are not familiar with matrices, then substitute for $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ from the second equation ($a_{n+1}=b_{n+2}-b_{n+1}$) into the first one and get a recurrence relation in $b_n$s. Now it should be easy to solve.

Comment: I'm not familiar with matrices but thanks, I realise I missed a pretty obvious substitution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $a_{n+1}=a_n+2b_n$, we get $$b_n=\frac12a_{n+1}-\frac12a_n$$and by incrementing $n$ by $1$, we also get $$\begin{align}a_{n+2}&=a_{n+1}+2b_{n+1}\\&=a_{n+1}+2a_n+2b_n\\&=a_{n+1}+2a_n+a_{n+1}-a_n\\&=2a_{n+1}+a_n\end{align}$$
So we get a homogeneous second-order recurrence relation. $$a_{n+2}-2a_{n+1}-a_n=0$$
Since the solutions to $$\lambda^2-2\lambda-1=0$$ are $\lambda=1\pm2$, we get that the general solution of the recurrence relation is $$a_n=A\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^n+B\left(1-\sqrt2\right)^n$$
Since $a_1=3$ and $a_2=7$, we get that $$A=\frac{1+\sqrt2}{2}\\B=\frac{1-\sqrt2}{2}$$
Therefore, $$\begin{align}a_n&=\frac{1+\sqrt2}{2}\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^n+\frac{1-\sqrt2}{2}\left(1-\sqrt2\right)^n\\&=\boxed{\frac12\left({1+\sqrt2}\right)^{n+1}+\frac12\left({1-\sqrt2}\right)^{n+1}}\end{align}$$
As you can see, as $n\rightarrow\infty$, the $\frac12\left({1-\sqrt2}\right)^{n+1}$ term tends to $0$, so $$a_n\approx\frac12\left({1+\sqrt2}\right)^{n+1}$$